# Is there misscompatbility between different RPi boards and camera revisions?

Tags: camera

I'm planning to buy a camera board for my RPi (I have RPi B+ and RPi2).
I see some sellers highlight that their cameras are compatible with certain RPi version.

Is it possible to buy an incompatible RPi camera (given that it isn't a third party CSI camera but one from the RPi foundation)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the foundation cameras work with all available RPi revisions (A, A+, B, B+, 2B, compute module). I can say this with some confidence having used the modules on all revisions (except the compute module - I haven't got my hands on one of those yet!).

The same is *probably* true of the third party camera modules given that all of them are based on the same chip (OV5647), but I'm not 100% certain there.